# CSS, regarding filling out buttons in a nav bar,

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I have a problem in CSS, me and a friend are just casually working on a webpage (we are both quite new to HTML and CSS).

Here is a code for the section:

```
.nav li {
 margin: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px;
 font: Times;
 text-align:center;
 float: inherit;
 }

.nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
padding: inherit;
}
```

When you look at the picture I have attached you can see that the button does not fully fill the nav-bar.

[here is the image (sorry for poor quality)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5YhG.jpg).

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Please paste your HTML as well.

Comment: We need your code, but I am pretty sure that it is an issue related to margin or padding.

Comment: the padding of 10px from <li> does not allow it to fill. You could be do more specific and target  <a> inside <li> for padding

Answer (score 1):

`.nav li` have padding , remove padding and apply padding to the `anchor` elements.

```
.nav li{
padding:0
}

.nav li a{
padding:10px;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the `li` elements have padding.

```
.nav li {
 margin: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px; // here
 font: Times;
 text-align:center;
 float: inherit;
}
```

Remove the padding from `li` and add it to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0h6vxtcn/9/) that should work.

PS. Colors are used for tests only and the trick is that you use `:hover` or `:active` on the `<li>` element